# Checkbox checked if the value is true in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have a checkbox when on certain condition we need to make the checkbox checked.For eg Whenever `accept()` function calls, it triggers `onApprovedDateChecked()` function by passing true as a parameter.Whenever i get `true` i need to make the checkbox to be checked.Can anyone help me to sort this out??

**component.html**

```
 <p-checkbox label="dsd" formControlName="fcont" binary="true" 
                               (onChange)="onChecked($event)"></p-checkbox>
```

**component.ts**

```
    accept(){
      onChecked(true)
    }

   onChecked(e: any){

     //make the checkbox to checked
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p-checkbox label="dsd" [(ngModel)]="status" 
formControlName="fcont" binary="true"(onChange)="onChecked($event)"></p-checkbox>
```

Now define status before constructor like this in your `ts` file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'component',
      templateUrl: './component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./component.scss']
    })
    export class RequestReturnComponent implements OnInit {
    status: boolean = false;
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    accept(){
     onChecked(true)
    }

    onChecked(e: any){
      this.status = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngModel with binary to change its boolean value

```
<p-checkbox label="dsd" [(ngModel)]="obj.status" 
formControlName="fcont" binary="true"(onChange)="onChecked($event)"></p-checkbox>
```

Set obj.status to true or false to change.

```
accept(){
 onChecked(true)
}

onChecked(e: any){
  this.obj.status = true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting Cannot read property 'status' of undefined error

Comment: You have to defined obj at the top in the component

Answer (score 0):

You may like the `async` pipe for this, the implementation for this would look like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'async-checkbox-pipe',
  template: '<input type="checkbox" [checked]="onApprovedDateChecked | async" /> Async checked'
})
export class AsyncCheckboxPipeComponent {
  onApprovedDateChecked = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    // use the observer to dispatch checked or not later on
      setTimeout(() => {
        return observer.next(true|false)
      }, 1500);
  });
}
```

Example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8cqcph

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```
<p-checkbox label="dsd" [checked]="checkValue" formControlName="fcont" (onChange)="onChecked($event)">
</p-checkbox>
```

## component.ts

```
//declare variable

checkValue:boolean = false;
```

## ---function---

```
accept(){
checkValue = true;
}
```